# Datagridview CellValidating is Not working perfectly

Tags: vb.net

I have 3 columns

- Item Name
- Quantity on Hand
- Quantity to transfer

the item name and the qty on hand is diplayed to the user
. If he tries to input a number  which is more than the Qty he has on Hand; i need a messageBox to pop up...

---

this what i have tried

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating

    With DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
                If e.ColumnIndex = 2 Then '' this is the  col index for qty to be transfered
                    If .Cells(2).Value > .Cells(1).Value Then
                        MessageBox.Show("You don't Have sufficient quantity ", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                        e.Cancel = True
                    End If
                End If
            End With
end sub
```

However the event is not firing the exact time I want. It allows me to leave the row without the message popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value isn't written to the cell yet, so use the value that is being passed to you from the event:

```
If Convert.ToInt32(e.FormattedValue) > Convert.ToInt32(.Cells(1).Value) Then
```

Side note: Set Option Strict On in your code since Value and FormattedValue return *objects*.

Comment: No errors, and its working. Thanks for the tip, will remember that for the future. Thanks.